# Simple absolute value inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove: for all $x\neq 0,$ $\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert > 2$ and $\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert = 2\iff x=\pm 1$

case 1: $x>0$

$$x+\frac{1}{x}> 2$$

$$x^2-2x+1>0$$

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{2+\sqrt{4-4}}{2}=1$$

Therefore $x\neq 1$

Case 2: $x< 0$

In the same manner we get $$x^2+2x+1>0$$

and $x\neq -1$

Now we need that both cases will occur simultaneously (?) so we get $x=\neq \pm 1$ for an equality and $x\neq 0$ for inequality

Comment: Speaking about your case 1. This says that the parabola which the inequality is equivalent to, is always above the $x$ axis and touches it in $x=1$. From that you can conclude that the inequality is always strict and only equal in $x=1$.

Comment: I am confused.  Since you say "$|x+ \frac{1}{x}|= 2$ you [b]cannot[/b] have "$|x+ \frac{1}{x}|> 2$.  Did you mean to say "or" rather than "and"?  That is $|x+ \frac{1}{x}|\ge 2$?  Also, having derived "x= 1" why do you then say "Therefore $x\ne 1$"?

Comment: I think the first part of the thing to prove should be $\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert \geq 2$  instead of $\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert > 2.$ Alternatively, you could say "$\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert > 2$ if $x\neq\pm1,$" but the "only if" direction of the second part of the statement makes this redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just AM-GM:
$$\frac{x^2+1}{2}\geq|x|,$$ which for $x\neq0$ gives which you wish:
$$\frac{x^2+1}{|x|}\geq2$$ or
$$\left|x+\frac{1}{x}\right|\geq2.$$

Comment: How did you get to $\frac{x^2+1}{2}\geq |x|$?

Comment: @gbox It's AM-GM: for non-negatives $a$ and $b$ we have $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$. In our case: $\frac{x^2+1}{2}\geq\sqrt{x^2\cdot1}=|x|$.

Comment: Thanks, or $|x|+|\frac{1}{x}|\geq|x+\frac{1}{x}|\geq 2$.
$|x|+\frac{1}{|x|}|\geq 2\iff \frac{|x|^2+1}{2}\geq |x|$ so $x\neq$

Comment: @gbox No! You can not do so. Indeed, $|x|+|\frac{1}{x}|\geq|x+\frac{1}{x}|$ and $|x|+|\frac{1}{x}|\geq2$, but why $|x+\frac{1}{x}|\geq2$ is true??? The similar wrong reasoning is the following. If $a>b$ and $a>c$ so $b>c$. It's wrong!

Comment: yes I have just realized that it is a mistake